# S3 getObjectCommand doesn't return the latest version of the file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I am using react and i am trying to get a json file from S3.

This is the package i use: `"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.332.0"`.

This is the code i run in order to get the s3 object:

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import env from "../env";

export const getS3Object = async ({
  tempCredentials,
  bucketName,
  objectKey,
}) => {
  try {
    if (!bucketName || !objectKey || !tempCredentials) {
      console.log(
        "No bucket name or object key or temp credentials was provided."
      );
      return;
    }
    const credentials = {
      accessKeyId: tempCredentials?.AccessKeyId,
      expireTime: tempCredentials?.Expiration,
      secretAccessKey: tempCredentials?.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: tempCredentials?.SessionToken,
    };
    const s3 = new S3Client({
      region: env.REACT_APP_REGION,
      credentials,
    });
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: objectKey,
    };
    const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
    const response = await s3.send(command);
    const responseString = await response.Body.transformToString();
    const result = JSON.parse(responseString);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I have a json file sitting in s3 bucket that is used for texts in my app.

The json is in the bucket and i have overridden it with a new json file with changed texts.

When i run the code above i keep on getting the same initial version of the json, in other words the texts in the app haven't changed.

The weird thing is i have an app in react native that is using the same code to get texts from the same bucket and if i edit a text and upload it to the bucket all i need to do is close and re open the app and the text is changed...

I have object versioning enabled if that helps.

TL;DR

This is what i tried:

1. Test: Running a react app that access a s3 bucket to get a json file after i uploaded the same json but with some changes.

   Result: Getting the first json without the changes.
2. Test: Running a react native app that access the same s3 bucket to get a different json file after i uploaded the same json but with some changes.

   Result: Getting the new json with the changes.

**Update:**

It turns out that opening the react app in incognito mode fixes the problem.

So I cleared the browser's cache and the problem is fixed.

Comment: Are you using object versioning?

Comment: Yes but in the documentation it says that you get the latest object if you don't specify a version id

Comment: You should `await response` and access  `.Body` on a subsequent line so that you can get your hands on the response headers, in addition to the body.  The version ID of the version S3 is returning will be on the headers, and you will probably then understand what is happening.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am not seeing anything relevant in the response like version id.
I noticed something weird, when I started the project on my home network I got the new texts but in the office I get the older...

Comment: @NivOhayon yes, that's weird.  But also, there should be a lot of different properties in the response, like `LastModified` and `VersionId` so it's not clear what you mean when you say you are not seeing anything relevant.  You might dump the response object and edit it into the body of this question.